# How can I use GET-request to get a sentence from http-server

Tags: java, sockets, http

I am working on a project that consists in making connection between two http-agents via http-protocol. So I am writing a java-program for that purpose. the client will send a GET-request to get a sentence from the http-server. That http-Server is a simple java-program, in which we find the following instruction:

```
final String id="03788444"
```

My Aim is to get this id from the server using GET-requet. **My small Java Server is running on localhost at port 80**. Basically my resource is that id, so I write the following:

```
GET /id HTTP/1.1
```

But I get nothing from the server.
From the  server-side I wrote the following:

```
"http/1.1 200 OK"
 blankline
 id
```

is it correct?
should I put the id in a txt-file and send the file by using http-protocol. I think that id is not a resource. So I should put it in a file???

```
public class Server {
     ....
    void send_response(){
        try {
            out= new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream());
            //status line
            out.print("http/1.1 200 OK");
            //blank line!!!
            out.print("");
            out.print(id);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    void close_connection(){
        out.close();        
    }
}
```

```
public class Client {
....

void sendGet(){

    final String request_line="GET /id http/1.1";
    PrintWriter out = null;
    .....
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(ag_socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        // Send request to http-agent
        out.println(request_line);
        out.println();   // blank line separating header & body
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        //out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the client code that is relevant to sending the `request` and the server code that is relevant to sending the `response`?

Comment: flush() doesn't print a blank line. Why are you writing your own HTTP server and your own HTTP client? There are dozens of correct, battlefield -tested, open source HTTP clients and servers. Don't write your own, especially if you don't really understand how HTTP works.

Comment: I would really recommend that you either use pre-existing HTTP libraries or study the HTTP standard before you write your own HTTP client and server. Your client and server are far far away from proper HTTP so it makes not sense to start based on your code on your missing knowledge.

Comment: I am emulating a device with a java program

Comment: I will not use very complicated http-commands. Just I want to ask for a resource and i want to get it. I want to program something primitive